# Text Overflow Issues with Printing an HTML Form

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with text-overflow when trying to print an HTML form.

You can see the issue in action at:
https://www.yandasmusic.com/Articles.asp?ID=304

In any given form field, if the data entered is longer than the width of the field itself, that extra data is cut off, and not printed. How can I avoid this? Is there a way with CSS to achieve a fluid text box that re-sizes based on the content entered?

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: What do you mean by "not printed"?

Comment: Sure, the form itself does an onsubmit="window.print();" when a user clicks I Agree. This brings up a print preview that prints the form. When a user enters data into any given field that is longer than the original width of the form field, that data is not printed.

Comment: What is delivering that print document? How can you modify that? Can you not just write simple lines? Like Name: AAAABBBBBBCCCCDDDD

Comment: Any reason why the input fields are so tiny? Just use up the available space on the screen.

Comment: Yea, I'm re-sizing them right now as a temporary solution. I was hoping for a responsive solution just in case someone decides to write a book for a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a fluid text box that re-sizes based on the content entered try this http://jsfiddle.net/tdhLyazo/

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $("input:text").keyup(
    function()
    {
     var size = $(this).prop('size')
      if($(this).val().length > size)
      {
      $(this).prop('size',size+1)
       } 
            }
 )

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" size="5">
```

Comment: Great solution Sarath. The only problem is that the code is just for an input:text box, and not a textarea. Would you possibly know how to modify your code to work on a text area as well?

Comment: you can make it working for a textarea by changing the selector as $("textarea") and using the cols property instead of size. you can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/84jsg77j/)